# Minimizing a function (cost function) of 3 variables

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, maxima-minima

I have to minimize the following cost function :
$$cost\_func(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\sum_{i=1}^{5} \left( z_i - \alpha - \beta e^{2x_i+y_i} - \gamma e^{4 x_i+2 y_i}\right)^2 $$
where $x_i,y_i,z_i, i=1,...,5$ are constants.
I know that there are deterministic,non-deterministic and mixed methods but is there any way to explore which one I can apply to this problem ?
Is there any idea what I can do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on if your $x,y,z$ are deterministic or stochastic variables. It looks pretty simple as the [linear least squares method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)).

Comment: To simplify the function, you could replace then constant term $e^{2x_i+y_i}$ by some constant $w_i$ and $e^{4x_i+2y_i}$ by $w_i^2$ accordingly. Then, calculate the gradient and find extremal points of your function. If there is not analytical solution, you could use a steepest descent search. Probably, the [Excel Sover](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-Solver-9ed03c9f-7caf-4d99-bb6d-078f96d1652c) would be sufficient to find a solution.

Comment: @AxelKemper how do you know that steepest descent will succeed? And what do you mean with the "if there is not analytical solution"?

Comment: If you do the suggested simplification, you end up with a long sum of linear and quadratic terms. It should be straight forward to calculate the three partial derivatives. But I haven't done it and thus don't know, if a zero gradient solution can be found right away. For quadratic functions, steepest descent will certainly succeed, as there are no local extrema and no discontinuities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the simplification

$$w_i = e^{2x_i+y_i}$$

$$v_i = w_i^2 = e^{4x_i+2y_i}$$

$$t_i = w_i^3 = e^{6x_i+3y_i}$$

$$u_i = w_i^4 = e^{8x_i+4y_i}$$

the following highly regular system of linear equation has to be solved:

$$5\alpha+\beta\sum_{i=1}^5w_i+\gamma\sum_{i=1}^5v_i = \sum_{i=1}^5z_i$$

$$\alpha\sum_{i=1}^5w_i + \beta\sum_{i=1}^5v_i + \gamma\sum_{i=1}^5t_i = \sum_{i=1}^5w_i z_i$$

$$\alpha\sum_{i=1}^5v_i + \beta\sum_{i=1}^5t_i + \gamma\sum_{i=1}^5u_i = \sum_{i=1}^5v_i z_i$$

For the resulting $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$, the gradient of the costfunction is zero.

Comment: Another question is it easy to prove that the matrix of the last system is positive definite ? Because it seems that it isn't.